# Summing the discretized values of the density function of $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ with a step of $1$ is equal to $1$?

Tags: normal-distribution, image-processing

Given the density function of the Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$:

$$ \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-0.5\,\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

I have noted that emprically, summing discretized values, with $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, leads to 1 irrespectively of the value of $\sigma$ (as Michael has pointed out in the comments, for certain values of $\sigma<1$ this does not hold), i.e.:

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-0.5\,\frac{x^2} {\sigma^2}\right), \qquad x\in\mathbb{Z} \\[10pt]
%
&=  \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum \left( \ldots,\,\exp\left(-0.5\,\frac{(-1)^2} {\sigma^2}\right),\, 1,\, \exp\left(-0.5\,\frac{1^2} {\sigma^2}\right),\,\ldots \right)
\end{align} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Is this a known fact? My concern is that I am not sure if this this is true since I was not able to prove it / find a proof.

*Motivation*: In image processing, when applying a [Gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) to an image, the filter/kernel used must properly average the neighbouring pixel values (e.g. [this great post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695/) explains its importance). Thereby the sum of the weights (filter/kernel values) must sum to $1$.

As a result, by sampling enough values ($\geq ceil(3\sigma)+1$, given the increasing decay of the function), and if we followed eq. $\eqref{1}$, we would end-up always with a *proper* filter without the need of any normalization.

---

This is the result of the empirical test that I've mentioned above:

[image]

where the number of samples (x-axis) to extract from the normal distribution is determined by $n = 2\text{ceil}(\text{cutoff}\cdot\sigma) + 1$.

As can be seen, by growing the number of samples (increasing the cutoff), we end up with a sum that tends to $1$.

The python code for reproducing it is the following:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sample_normal_mean0(sigma, cutoff=3.0):
    """ 
    Create an array, centered at 0, of length determined by the cutoff freqency 
    """
    # length of the array (number of samples)
    n = 2 * ceil(cutoff * sigma) + 1
    # discrete values
    x = np.linspace(-(n//2), n//2, n)
    # density function at these values
    f = np.exp(-0.5 * (x**2) / (sigma**2)) / (sigma * sqrt(2. * np.pi))
    return f


def emprical_test(cutoffs, sigma, ax):
    """ Plot the sum of the discretized values as a function of \sigma """
    # XY coordinates:
    x = 2 * np.ceil(cutoffs * sigma) + 1
    y = [sample_normal_mean0(sigma, cutoff_i).sum() for cutoff_i in cutoffs]
    # plot
    ax.plot(x, y, '-o', lw=2, label=f'$\sigma$={sigma:.1f}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # standard deviations
    sigmas_to_test = np.linspace(start=1, stop=20, num=20)
    # cutoff frequencies
    cutoffs_to_test = np.arange(start=1, stop=10, step=1.0)
    # create plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for sigma_i in sigmas_to_test:
        emprical_test(cutoffs_to_test, sigma_i, ax)
    
    ax.set_xlabel('#samples = 2 * ceil(cutoff * sigma) + 1', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Discretized sum', fontsize=12)
    ax.legend(loc='center right', ncol=2)
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This is quite false as far as I can tell. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Lemniscatic_values

Comment: Thanks for your response @QiaochuYuan . However I cannot grasp the idea following that page - I attribute it to have a higher difficulty than what I can grasp :_).

Comment: It seems to work remarkably well for $\sigma^2\geq 1$, but not so well when $\sigma^2<1$.  Wolfram-Alpha gives a value of 1.78429 when $\sigma^2=0.05$, but it gives a value that it cannot distinguish from 1 when $\sigma^2=1$ or $\sigma^2=2.2$.

Comment: Thank you for the catch @Michael .  I forgot to test it when  $\sigma < 1$.  I am now intrigued as to why it apparently works when $\sigma\geq1$

Comment: I don't think it's a surprise that it works better for larger $\sigma$. You're approximating the integral of the pdf, which we know is $1$. The larger the variance, the flatter the curve, which would suggest a smaller error. This heuristic can probably be made formal in the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a consequence of the remarkable [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).
In your context, with $f_\sigma(x)$ denoting the above Gaussian distribution density, its Fourier transform (using the normalization as in the link)  is given by
$$ \hat{f}_\sigma(w) = \exp\left(-\frac12 (2\pi \sigma)^2 w^2\right) ,$$
and the P-S formula simply states that
$$ \sum_{k\in {\Bbb Z}} f_\sigma(k) = \sum_{w\in {\Bbb Z}} \hat{f}_\sigma(w).$$

As an example, for $\sigma=1$ you get
$$ \sum_{k\in {\Bbb Z}} f_1(k) =
    \sum_{w\in {\Bbb Z}} \exp(-2\pi^2 w^2) = 1 + 2 \exp(-2\pi^2) 
   + 2 \exp(-8\pi^2) + \cdots.$$
The second term on the RHS is of order $5.35 \times 10^{-9}$ and the third of order $10^{-34}$. Approximating by $1$ is good for $\sigma$ large,
but bad when $\sigma$ is small.